# generate reason codes from shap values

Tags: pandas, shap

I am developing a credit probability of default model in python and would like to use shap values for generating reasons codes which the worst 3 reason codes.

I found this very useful article on how to do that. It uses ndarray datasets. https://medium.com/@wenzhang.ds/create-reason-code-via-shap-value-for-gmb-model-2e150837c8fe
However, the code is giving me error for the pandas data frame I am using and I dont know how to modify the code to ingest pandas data frame. It is failing in this line.

```
sorted_feature_names = [feature_names[i] for i in sorted_indices]
```

Feature names I have is a list and it is not indexed.

Can you please help?

Comment: Can you provide the values and types of `feature_names` and `sorted_indices` ?

Comment: I am using the breast cancer dataset converted to pandas dataframe. That is basically a smaller version of my data. Once you created a pandas dataframe, you can use list(df.columns) to created a list of columns.

Comment: 1) Be more specific, down to exactly what variable you assigned `list(df.columns)` to. 2) Add the clarification to the question with an edit.

Comment: Please [ask] and [reprex]